# How does 3D picking work in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx-8

Unfortunately I could not find any good tutorial for picking api.

Can anyone give me a brief tutorial about it or some useful links?

**Update**

```
world.setOnMouseClicked((event)->{
    PickResult res = event.getPickResult();
    System.out.println("res "+res);

    //you can get a reference to the clicked node like this 
    if (res.getIntersectedNode() instanceof Node){
        ((Node)res.getIntersectedNode()).setTranslateZ(-50);
    }
});
```

The code above only work on the first node that I click.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: I put complete code, I don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work just fine without much understanding.  My guess is it takes the element closest to the camera (ie. in front) in the 2D representation of where you clicked.  It doesn't matter which face you click, it always gets the right node.

The code is very simple.  I've made a scene with a `Parent` called world that has 3D elements.
package simple3dboxapp;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.PickResult;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Material;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Simple3dBoxApp extends Application {
    public Rotate rx = new Rotate();
    { rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS); }
    public Rotate ry = new Rotate();
    { ry.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS); }
    public Rotate rz = new Rotate();
    { rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS); }
    Translate t = new Translate();
    private final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    {camera.getTransforms().addAll(t, rz, ry, rx);}

    Label data = new Label();{data.setWrapText(true);data.setPrefHeight(200);}

    public Parent createContent() {
        Group root = new Group();       

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            Box box = new Box(50, 50, 50);
            Text text = new Text("Hi "+i);
            ImageView iv = new ImageView("file:apple-touch-icon.png");
            Image im = iv.getImage();
            Material m = new PhongMaterial(Color.CYAN, im, null, null, null);
            box.setMaterial(m);
            box.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-250 + i * 50 , -100, -100 + i * 50));
            text.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-250 + i * 50 , 0, -100 + i * 50));
            iv.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-250 + i * 50 , +100, -100 + i * 50));
            root.getChildren().addAll(box,text,iv);
        }

        camera.setNearClip(1);
        camera.setFarClip(2000);
        camera.setFieldOfView(100);

        // Use a SubScene       
        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root, 500,500);
        subScene.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        subScene.setCamera(camera);
        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(subScene);
        return group;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Parent world = createContent();
        world.setFocusTraversable(true);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(world,data);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        world.setOnKeyPressed((evt)->{
            switch (evt.getCode()){
                case UP:
                    rx.setAngle(rx.getAngle()+5);
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    rx.setAngle(rx.getAngle()-5);
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    t.setX(t.getX()+10);
                    //camera.setTranslateX(camera.getTranslateX()+10);
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    t.setX(t.getX()-10);
                    //camera.setTranslateX(camera.getTranslateX()-10);
                    break;
                case Z:
                    double zoom = evt.isShortcutDown()?-10:+10;
                    t.setZ(t.getZ()+zoom);
                    //camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ()+zoom);
                    break;
            }
        });

        world.setOnMouseClicked((event)->{
                PickResult res = event.getPickResult();
                data.setText("res "+res);
                if (res.getIntersectedNode() instanceof Box){
                    ((Box)res.getIntersectedNode()).setMaterial(
                            new PhongMaterial(event.isShiftDown() ? Color.BLACK : Color.RED));
                }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

And this is the result from clicking a Box

res PickResult [node = Box@1dc02a4, point = Point3D [x = 12.361420184603276, y = 15.984395060669844, z = -5.0], distance = 1866.0254037844388, texCoord = Point2D [x = 0.6236142018460328, y = 0.8196879012133969]

[PickResult javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/PickResult.html)

[image]

Comment: I have the similar code, I have some ImageView nodes. I want to change the Z axis of node when I click on it. now when I click on one of the nodes, the z axis change as I expected but the rest of nodes will be not captured with pickResult anymore

Comment: I think it is because of you are using 3D nodes. if you change the Box to something like ImageView or Button, then you will see the issue.

Comment: It must need the getTransforms() method.  ImageView and Text both work for me.  Buttons barely even show up.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your app?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I have found the problem. if you add the boxes to the pane instead of group then it will not work properly. Now I'm trying to change all the layouts in my app to groups to make it work.